# Print only on recto (one paper side) with Word.interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, printers

I'm trying to print a document, only on recto, and not recto-verso.

So, I print my document with `Word.Interop` and before open document, set default printer parameters like this :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;

PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    settings.PrinterName = printer;
    if (settings.IsDefaultPrinter)
    {
        settings.Duplex = Duplex.Simplex;
    }
}
wordApp.Documents.Open(fullPath);

wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
wordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(false);

wordApp.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

This print well, but always in recto-verso. How can I change default printer parameters. Why `settings.Duplex = Duplex.Simplex;` doesn't work?

I checked, and Duplex value is `simplex` when the document open.

Comment: Are you trying to print on only 1 side of the paper, or every second page of the word document?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have try many time but it's not working. Have another ways ?